# Error while installing WSL for windows 11

Tags: windows, powershell, command

when i run the command on administrator settings on my windows 11

```
wsl --install
```

it shows me the following error

```
a connection with the server could not be established
```

I searched youtube too for the fixes but none worked

Comment: AFAIR is pulls the latest installer off of Github. Can you browse github.com from the same machine?

Comment: Did you start Powershell by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin?

Comment: Yes i did run as admin @jdweng

Comment: Yes , i can browse github . No problems here ! @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Three things can be wrong 1) Having Route to machine 2) Having credentials to login to remote machine 3) Having Admin on remote machine. The connection is a HTTPS connection which uses TLS.  So you could have an issue with the TLS certificate.  What I like to use for debugging is a File Explorer and see if you can read files on remote machine which will help isolate what is not working.

Comment: Why has this question be closed? This could be an ISP issue. I'm facing the same. It may not be a Windows/Microsoft issue but it is an issue for the user. Since this is not a ticket for Microsoft support, it should not be closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi I was having same error. I am Indian using Jio Fiber. I connected to VPN to solve the error. It seems that Jio prevents connection to certain url such as https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/WSL/master/distributions/DistributionInfo.json which are needed for wsl linux installation. You can check by trying to open above link in chrome and running network diagnostics. Basically the above url gets called at the end when you do `wsl --install`.

Answer (score -3):

For some countries it's need to use VPN for work with wsl.
after vpn installation, connect to vpn and open the powershell as administrator at the end add this command to powershell:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy proxy_ip:proxy_port
```